# How to limit express API request by pricing plan

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, express-rate-limit

I am building a public API with a pricing plan.
I want to limit API requests to each account and its plan.
I use NodeJS and ExpressJS

These code cannot run properly, i cannot next() after return the data. How to solve this middlerware?

```js
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const freePlan = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 5,
    message: {
        error: "Try again after 1 minute"
    }
})

const premiumPlan = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 30,
    message: {
        error: "Try again after 1 minute"
    }
})

function limiter(req, res, next ) {
    switch (req.body.plan) {
        case "free":
            return freePlan
            break;
    
        case "big":
            return premiumPlan
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
    next();
}

module.exports = limiter;
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const limiter = require("../middlewares/limiter");
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', limiter, async (req, res) => {
    res.send('OK');
})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I've never used `express-rate-limit`, but from a glance at the code I think you should be calling the `freePlan` and `premiumPlan` functions in your limiter middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is i found answer from [github](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/227#issuecomment-805879651) and sharing here..

```
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

function isPremium(req) {
  //... your logic to return true false based on premium plan or not
}

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  // see https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit#max
  max: function(req, res) {
    if (isPremium(req)) {
      return 30;
    }
    return 5;
  }
});

//  apply to all requests
app.use(limiter);
```